# react native animation , Easing.bounce force bounce only two times

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to for Easing.bounce to bounce only 2 times? 
And not 3 times;

```
Animated.timing(
    this.y_translate,
    {
        delay: 0,
        toValue: 1,
        easing: Easing.bounce,
        duration: 1000,
    }
 ).start();
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no.

Long answer is to look at the docs.

You'll see that [`Easing.bounce`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/easing.html#bounce) is based off of [this mathematical definition](http://easings.net/#easeInBounce) that has the bounce happening 4 times. You can see exactly how they do this in their [example code](https://github.com/ai/easings.net/blob/e28443ff094f094144ab6754c8dd6a799bfe8cec/vendor/jquery.easing.js#L154) (note the `easeInBounce`, `easeOutBounce`, and `easeInOutBounce` functions). If you compare this with what is in the React Native source for [`Easing.bounce`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/7d20de412b37a35951e615d98509573dc1a24bcb/Libraries/Animated/src/Easing.js#L186), you'll find the same mathematical calculations.

So if you want to have a two bounce effect, you'll need to do the math yourself. For example, you can create your own `Easing` class with it's own `bounce` method. Then use it in your animation in place of `Easing.bounce`.

```
// You can also extend Easing and just define a new method (or override)
// if you want access to Easing's other methods.
class MyEasing {
  /**
   * Provides a two bounce effect.
   */
  static bounce(t: number): number {
    /* Code Goes Here */
    return something;
  }
}

// ... in your code ...
Animated.timing(
    this.y_translate,
    {
        delay: 0,
        toValue: 1,
        easing: MyEasing.bounce,
        duration: 1000,
    }
 ).start();
 });
```

How you do this calculation though is outside the scope of the question, so I'll leave that for your to figure out.

Comment: thank you, but the hardest part is what I put inside the bounce function (: ,
that what I am actually looking for

Comment: @AharonVishinsky You're going to have to give it a try first. StackOverflow isn't a place to post questions expecting someone to write the code from scratch for you. [There's an expectation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that you try other avenues for solving this yourself and coming here to post when you run into a specific problem. If this was just a broad question of how to write the math part, I would have just flagged it for closing as off-topic. Also being that I've reduced the problem down to just math, this arguably isn't even the right StackExchange to post on anymore.